# Jquery toggle between divs

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I'm currently experimenting with JQuery, my aim is to have a few divs which can be toggled between using arrows. I have a JSFiddle which shows what I have so far, but I think there is a simpler way to achieve what I want to achieve.

I want to be able to keep toggling through the divs when I press the arrows rather than using show and hide.

http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal90/ZW3kY/

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzS36/) where you can add as many `div`s as you want to your DOM now. The solution is to look for `next` or `first sibling` of current visible element.

```
currentElem.hide();
if (currentElem.next().length > 0) {
  currentElem = currentElem.next().show();
} else {
  currentElem = currentElem.siblings().first().show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is your modified fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hz2nT/1/

regards,
Ishan